# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Type'. Flutter ListView Builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was making a horizontal `ListView.builder` of "Cards", but in the `itemBuilder` option, in the item argument, I typed `buildCard(item: int [index])` but it showed me the error :

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Type'. Try defining the
> operator '[]'.

I would like to solve this error please.

My code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class CardItem {
  final String assetImage;
  final String title;

  const CardItem({
    required this.assetImage,
    required this.title,
  });
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<CardItem> items = [
    CardItem(title: 'Card1', assetImage: 'images/movie/01.webp'),
    CardItem(title: 'Card2', assetImage: 'images/movie/02.png'),
    CardItem(title: 'Card3', assetImage: 'images/movie/03.png'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
            height: 250,
            child: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCard(item: int[index]),
                separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(width: 12),
                itemCount: 3)));
  }

  Widget buildCard({
    required CardItem item,
  }) =>
      Container(
          width: 170,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(item.assetImage),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use items list not int in buildCard(item: items[index])

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<CardItem> items = [
    CardItem(title: 'Card1', assetImage: 'images/movie/01.webp'),
    CardItem(title: 'Card2', assetImage: 'images/movie/02.png'),
    CardItem(title: 'Card3', assetImage: 'images/movie/03.png'),
  ];

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCard(item: items[index]),
              separatorBuilder: (context, _) => SizedBox(height: 12),
              itemCount: 3)));
}

Widget buildCard({
  required CardItem item,
}) =>
    Container(
        width: 170,
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Image.network('https://github.com/flutter/plugins/raw/master/packages/video_player/video_player/doc/demo_ipod.gif?raw=true') 
,
            )
          ],
        ));
}
```

Comment: Yes but with that I come withe a blank screen, and a error : Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: set hight fro card in buildCard fubction

Comment: But then there is just one card that appear

Comment: I will edit the answer

Comment: there's still only one card

Comment: copy the provided class and it will work